# error 413 request entity too large godaddy server while uploading large image

Tags: .htaccess, upload, http-status-code-413

I have added this one in php5.ini file but this does not solved my problem-

> post_max_size = 750M  upload_max_filesize = 750M  max_execution_time =
>   5000  max_input_time = 5000  memory_limit = 1000M

I found one more suggestion in htaccess but not finding where should I append this one (not sure that this one will solve my problem)

> LimitRequestBody

At present If I upload arround 700 mb file then it is ok but when I tried 900 mb or more sized image then it gives me this error. If can tell any other way to solve my problem that will really be helpful for me.